# Error 1 when compiling cydia

Tags: compiler-errors, terminal, cydia

When I trie to compile cydia (from git://git.saurik.com/cydia.git, just copy and paste it into browser bar) Terminal gives me this:

```
Leos-MacBook-Pro:cydia leogalli$ make
[cycc] SDURLCache/SDURLCache.m
[cycc] Menes/invocationWithSelector.mm
[cycc] Menes/radixSortWithSelector.mm
[cycc] Menes/yieldToSelector.mm
[cycc] CyteKit/MFMailComposeViewController-MailToURL.mm
[cycc] CyteKit/TableViewCell.mm
[cycc] CyteKit/ViewController.mm
[cycc] CyteKit/WebScriptObject-Cyte.mm
[cycc] CyteKit/WebView.mm
[cycc] CyteKit/WebViewController.mm
[cycc] CyteKit/WebViewTableViewCell.mm
[cycc] CyteKit/dispatchEvent.mm
[cycc] CyteKit/stringWithUTF8Bytes.mm
[cycc] Cydia/LoadingView.mm
[cycc] Cydia/LoadingViewController.mm
[cycc] Cydia/MIMEAddress.mm
[cycc] MobileCydia.mm
[cycc] Version.mm
[cycc] Sources.mm
[cycc] lookup3.c
[link] SDURLCache/SDURLCache.o Menes/invocationWithSelector.o Menes/radixSortWithSelector.o Menes/yieldToSelector.o CyteKit/MFMailComposeViewController-MailToURL.o CyteKit/TableViewCell.o CyteKit/ViewController.o CyteKit/WebScriptObject-Cyte.o CyteKit/WebView.o CyteKit/WebViewController.o CyteKit/WebViewTableViewCell.o CyteKit/dispatchEvent.o CyteKit/stringWithUTF8Bytes.o Cydia/LoadingView.o Cydia/LoadingViewController.o Cydia/MIMEAddress.o MobileCydia.o Version.o Sources.o lookup3.o
ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MobileCydia] Error 1
Leos-MacBook-Pro:cydia leogalli$ make
[link] SDURLCache/SDURLCache.o Menes/invocationWithSelector.o Menes/radixSortWithSelector.o Menes/yieldToSelector.o CyteKit/MFMailComposeViewController-MailToURL.o CyteKit/TableViewCell.o CyteKit/ViewController.o CyteKit/WebScriptObject-Cyte.o CyteKit/WebView.o CyteKit/WebViewController.o CyteKit/WebViewTableViewCell.o CyteKit/dispatchEvent.o CyteKit/stringWithUTF8Bytes.o Cydia/LoadingView.o Cydia/LoadingViewController.o Cydia/MIMEAddress.o MobileCydia.o Version.o Sources.o lookup3.o
ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MobileCydia] Error 1
```

So what does this mean? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o for architecture armv6

This error means the linker command in the makefile is requesting the binary to be armv6 CPU compatible, but this isn't possible with Xcode 4.5 as the iOS 6 SDK doesn't support armv6 any more.

The solution is to download the Xcode 4.4.1 DMG from Apple, copy its Xcode.app to /Applications/Xcode441.app and then `xcode-select` it:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode441.app/Contents/Developer
```